# K8Studio Prometheus Metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Does anybody knows how to configure prometheus metrics in K8Studio?

I can not find the service name and the port, the left panel is always black and does not refresh.
I also try different namespaces combination, since prometheus installation have many diferent services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just need to go to the settings of your cluster and type
default/Prometheus-server:80

[image]